# How to expose and call a jQuery plugin's public methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been asked to try to stop this slideshow when the last slide is reached

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Fakwx/

Here is the code I need to modify - added bonus would be to grab the number of slides from the object too

```
$(function(){
  $('#slides').slides({
    animationComplete: function(current) {
      // how to stop on the last slide:
      // a) get the number of slides from the object - called total in the js
      // b) call the stop() or pause() on the slideshow object
      if (current>=????.total) {
         ????.stop();
      }
    },            
    preload: true,
  .
  .
  });
});
```

Here is the site http://slidesjs.com/ - I have not found any example I could use but people well versed in jQuery should be able to tell me how to call this function from http://slidesjs.com/js/slides.jquery.js :

```
function stop() {  // clear interval from stored id
  clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
}
```

---

Please tell me how you found the object since I have never tried to enumerate jQuery methods.

In Plain JS I would do something like

```
var txt = "";
for (var o in object) {
  txt += '\n'+o+':'+object[o]
}
...
```

but in this case, I am not sure how to access the slideshow object and to figure out what to call stop on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "elem" referenced in the `stop()` method is the element that the behavior was bound to; in this case, `$("#slides")`.  Apparently, the script stores the repeating interval using jQuery's `data()` method.  Here is some working code that retrieves that interval using the same `data()` method and uses the number of images (minus the two buttons) to determine when to stop.

**Note**: Calculating the number of images each time is inefficient.  The total count should be stored in a variable, but I left it in the `if()` statement for clarity.

```
$(function(){
  $('#slides').slides({
     animationComplete: function(current) {
       // how to stop on the last slide
       // a) get the number of slides from the object
       // b) call the stop() or pause() on the slideshow object
       if (current >= $("#slides img").length - 2) // Subtract Two arrows
          clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
       },            
       preload: true,
       preloadImage: 'http://slidesjs.com/img/loading.gif',
       play: 5000,
       pause: 2500,
       slideSpeed: 600,
       hoverPause: true
   });
});
```

Updated JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Fakwx/2/

Comment: Excellent. Well spotted on the data thing.

Comment: I added $(".pagination").remove();
          $(".prev").remove();
          $(".next").remove(); to remove the arrows and pagination too